# How do I calculate reversible id for each move on a board game?

Tags: python, algorithm

I try to build a 6x6 board game using pyhton. Every pieces can move 4 directions which are top, down, left and right. I am using a legacy code which is implemented for checkers.

```
------------------
6 |x x - - o o |
5 |x x - - o o |
4 |- - - - - - |
3 |- - - - - - |
2 |o o - - x x |
1 |o o - - x x |
------------------
   a b c d e f
```

I have to write a function that is capable to calculate uniqe and reversible id for each movement. For example if a piece can move to all directions each movement should have different id.

```
def calc_move_id(x0, x1, y0, y1):
    """ Calculates move_id. 
    """
    # directions = (1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)
    # x0, y0 -> start point 
    # x1, y1 -> destination point
    dx, dy = x1 - x0, y1 y0
    direction = 0
    if dx > 0 and dy < 1:
        direction = 0
    elif dx < 1  and dy > 0:
        direction = 1
    elif dx < 0 and dy < 1:
        direction = 2
    else:
        direction = 3
    start = int((8 * self.y0 + self.x0) / 2)  # 1d-index of black squares
    length = abs(dx)
    vector = direction + (length - 1) * 4
    move_id = (vector << 5) | start
    return move_id

def parse_move(move_id):
    """ @see calc_move_id() """
    start = action & 31  # start/from
    action = action >> 5
    vector = action
    length = int(vector / 4) + 1
    direction_id = vector % 4
    direction = Move.__directions[direction_id]
    x0, y0 = (start % 4) * 2, int(start / 4)
    if y0 % 2 == 1:
        x0 += 1
    x1, y1 = x0 + direction[0] * length, y0 + direction[1] * length
    assert (
            0 <= x0
            and x0 < 6
            and 0 <= x1
            and x1 < 6
            and 0 <= y0
            and y0 < 6
            and 0 <= y1
            and y1 < 6
    ), ("Illegal action: " + str(action) + "=>" + str((x0, y0, x1, y1)))
    return (x0, x1, y0, y1)
```

Above code doesn't work because its throw assertion error in parse_move function. 
How can i achieve that ?  What should i use ? (ex. decode, encode, bitwise, bitmask implementation)

Comment: Just put that in a dictionary whose keys are incremental IDs and value for each ID is the move.

Comment: Wouldn't an id simply be the location a piece is at and the location it moves to? For example 1a1b is the movement from position 1a to 1b? Do you need anything more complex than that?

Comment: Not sure what kind of information you have to encode, so maybe we can start textual. Is ist "From 1a to 1b" or is it "1 field to the east"? The later would mean that "From 1a to 1b" and "From 1b to 1c" are the same move and get the same id.

Comment: Or maybe each piece on the board could be an object with a list of sequential movements made like `ul` for one position up and left, and `r` for one position to the right etc.

Comment: I need that all possible moves in a binary vector. Because i will put in deep learning model. So think it as hackerrank test, answer just my question i know what are alternative  solutions. Don't put down vote.

Comment: If you are trying to solve a HackerRank test then there is no point in asking for help here. We are not going to solve the problem for you. We can just point you what you are doing wrong... IF you provide the code you have so far. SO is not a place for asking for free coding services.

Comment: @accdias i think you didn't understand what is the point of the question. I try to do this for all possible moves on the board for every state. It has to be in reversible way.

Comment: @fuat and yet you didn't show us what you have tried so far. Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips on those articles.

Comment: first change instead of `0 < x0 and x0 < 6` to `0 <= x0 <= 6` this will make your logic more readable ... second i think `action` is undefined in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reserve three bits for x0, three for y0, one for whether the move is horizontal or vertical, and one for whether it is "forward" or "backward" along that axis.

```
def calc_move_id(x0, x1, y0, y1):
    return x0*32 + y0*4 + (x1-x0+y1-y0+1) + abs(x1-x0)

def parse_move(move_id):
    x0 = move_id//32
    y0 = (move_id//4) % 8
    delta = (move_id & 2) - 1
    return (x0, x0+delta, y0, y0) if move_id % 2 else (x0, x0, y0, y0+delta)
```

This is assumes that both methods are called with valid arguments.

Comment: Did you test that code ? it seems  parse_move does not return the calc_move_id inputs.

Comment: Yes, I tested it. Note that the coordinates are zero-based.

Comment: but in parse_move function you return x0 and y0 twice. calc_move_id function generate unique id for each move that is ok but parse_move method does not seems work fine i have test function, i can share with you if you want.

Comment: Here is my test code: https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/testReversible?language=python3 Yes, either the x coordinate or the y coordinate stays the same in any valid move (according to your description), so that is why they reoccur. Where `delta` occurs, that is where the only change happens in a valid move.

Answer (score 2):

if you need to encode `x1,y1 -> x2,y2` as a single value that can be reversed  you can use the struct module to encode the 4 bytes into a binary string, which can then be converted to an unsigned int

```
import struct
def move_id(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    # encode the 4 bytes into a binary string eg '\x04\x05\x06\x05'
    encoded_bytes = struct.pack('bbbb',*[x1,y1,x2,y2])
    # then convert the string back into a single int
    return struct.unpack("I",encoded_bytes)[0]

def decode_move(encoded_move):
    return struct.unpack("bbbb",struct.pack("I",*[encoded_move,]))

print(move_id(1,2,3,4)) # 67305985
print(decode_move(67305985)) #[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Thanks to you i learned struct module, i did not know that. But i accept that it was a silly question just because concatenating numbers is also a solution just simple as.